# hide a particular column on xAxis highchart Column Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can i hide/show a praticular column in the Column Chart of Highcharts api.
i have a single series.
 The column to be hidden lies on the xaxis.
For sine Chart, `chart.series[4].hide() /show()` works fine
and for Pie Chart, `chart.series[0].data[0].setVisible(false);`
works fine. But i am not able to figure out the solution for Column Chart. Please Help!

Comment: Any other option than to temporarily remove the data from the xaxis

Answer (score 4):

You can use Element.hide() and Element.show(), so for example:

```
var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.hide();
chart.series[0].data[0].dataLabel.hide();
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Worked like a charm!
But i cannot re-position the columns. And the column name is still visible on the xAxis.

Comment: You want to remove column and also whole category? In that case, you need to use `setData()` and `setCategories()` with removed data.

Comment: Hi Pawel, can you show an example of using setData and setCategories?

Comment: @HimanshuSoni: Did you get it to work? were you able to re position columns?

Comment: I am not aware of the latest release. But, at that time I had to manually remove that column and hold them in another variable

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you help me out @PawelFus ?

Comment: What in my solution doesn't work for you? It hides label+shape on the chart.

Comment: for column charts it's the point object's graphic.hide() / graphic.show() that controls the column visibility. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smx7W/34/)